# boundedness and convergence under integral implies weak convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

I am trying to proof the following:

> Let $(\Omega,\mu)$ be a measure space, $1<p<\infty$.
>   Then weak convergence of $(f_n)$ to $f$ in $L^p(\Omega,\mu)$ is equivalent to $(f_n)$ being bounded and $\int_M f_n \to \int_M f$, for any measurable $M$ with finite $\mu$-volume.

I have a proven "$\Rightarrow$", by stating that weak convergence implies boundedness in general, and that integration over $M$ is a linear map to the underlying field i.e. a linear functional.
But I do not know how to approach the other direction. Of course I would be very happy to show this direction as well without making use of the isomorphism $(L^p)^* \to L^q$ for $p,q$ Hölder-conjugate, but I have not found a way yet.

(Unfortunately I don't know that much about measure theory, this is kind of a problem for me here.)

Comment: What is $M{}{}{}$?

Comment: @Jose27 Oh sorry I forgot about that, I edited my question.

Comment: Sketch: Write $\int_M f= \int_\Omega 1_Mf$, where $1_M$ is the indicator function of $M$ (i.e. it's one on $M$ and zero otherwise). Use this to show that $\int_\Omega \varphi f_n \to \int_\Omega \varphi f$ for every simple function $\varphi$.

Comment: Are you assuming that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite?

Comment: @Jose27 I already had the idea to rewrite $\int_M f_n$ using the indicator function, I also guess that I can show that $\int_M \varphi f_n \to \int_M \varphi f$ for $\varphi$ being a simple function. But how can I show the proposition for $\varphi$ being not a simple function?

Comment: @Michh No, I do not.

Comment: We use density of simple functions in $L^q$ (that this works will require boundedness of the sequence). As for a proof without appealing to the Riesz representation of $(L^p)^*$ I'm not sure at the moment.